# Randomly generated multidimensional Boolean pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this function randomly generating true/false values and assigning them to a multidimensional pointer, then returning the pointer.

```
bool** generateMap()
{

    int randNum = 0;
    int X = 7;
    int Y = 7;

    bool** MAP = new bool*[X];
    for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
        MAP[i] = new bool[Y];

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        int rooms = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
                if (rooms < 10)
                {
                    randNum = rand() % 6;
                    switch (randNum)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        MAP[x][y] = true;
                        ++rooms;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        MAP[x][y] = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        MAP[x][y] = false;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        MAP[x][y] = false;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        MAP[x][y] = false;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        MAP[x][y] = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
        }
    }
    return MAP;
}
```

It compiles but there is a run time error, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

`X` and `Y` both equal 7, but then you say: `for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)` - so you are running off the end of the arrays. The arrays go 0..6 but you access index 7.

You would be much better off with `for (int x = 0; x < X; x++)` - that is the whole point of making those values symbolic rather than just hardcoding 7.

You also stop setting values once you hit "10 rooms" - a comment about using the default value is probably in order (why not break the loop once you have populated 10 rooms?) - last but not least: by using a for in this way, there is no guarantee you'll actually get any rooms. They could all come up false...